# While loop not ending even with correct string input via Console.ReadLine

Tags: c#

I wrote a while loop to reject user input and ask for input again if they don't choose either "sword" of "bow" via Console.ReadLine.

I expected the program to jump to if statement when user input "sword" or "bow" but the actual output is that the program prints "Invalid Answer." and asks for input over and over again and does not jump to the if statement below no matter what.

How do I fix the bug and make the while loop end when the user gives the input "sword" or "bow"?

```
string weapon;
Console.WriteLine("Take the bow or take the sword?");
weapon = Console.ReadLine();
while(weapon != "bow" || weapon != "sword")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid answer.");
    Console.WriteLine("Take the bow or take the sword?");
    weapon = Console.ReadLine();
}
if (weapon == "sword")
{
    Console.WriteLine("You took the sword.");
}
else if (weapon == "bow")
{
    Console.WriteLine("You took the bow.");
}
```

Comment: `weapon != "bow" || weapon != "sword"` is equivalent to `!(weapon == "bow" && weapon == "sword")`, which is always true. `weapon` can't be two different things at the same time.

Comment: This is bad `while(weapon != "bow" || weapon != "sword")`

Comment: Thank you, I deleted the `weapon != sword` and it works fine now. But I'm curious as to whether there is a way to write it so that it would reject everything but "sword" and "bow"?

Comment: `while(weapon != "bow" && weapon != "sword")`

Comment: If you want to be fancy: `while (!new [] { "bow", "sword" }.Contains (weapon))`. Or, closer to your code `while (!(while(weapon == "bow" || weapon == "sword"))` or `while(weapon != "bow" && weapon != "sword"))`. Read all those out loud, then read what you wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the semantics of `||`, `weapon != "bow" || weapon != "sword"` is true when at least one of:

1. `weapon != "bow"`
2. `weapon != "sword"`

is true, in which case the loop will continue. However, note that at least of the two will always be true. `weapon` is either "bow", in which case 2 is true, or `weapon` is "sword", in which case 1 is true, or `weapon` is something else, in which case both 1 and 2 are true.

You want the loop to continue only when `weapon` is something else, i.e. when *both* 1 and 2 are true. Therefore, you should use `&&`:

```
while (weapon != "bow" && weapon != "sword")
```